# Unable to create SQL Join query

Tags: sql, join

Table I

```
ID  LinkId
1     0
2     1
3     2
```

Table 2

```
ID  IntersectionID  X   Y
1       5          100  200
2       6          300  400
3       7          800  500
```

Table 3

```
ID  IntersectionID  Sequence_number linkId  LinkDirection
1        5              0             0       Positive
1        5              1             1       negative
2        6              0             0       negative
```

I want a single query giving me the following

```
ID  LinkId  X(start) Y(Start) X(End) Y(End)
1      0      100     200      300    400
```

For every row in Table 1, get its IntersectionID from table 3(using linked field),(link direction- positive means start point and negative means end point). Then go to table 2 and fill x,y values.

Help me achieve it.

Tried this query. Unable to get it.

```
select r1.id id, r1.linkid base_link_id, r2.X startX,r2.Y startY from  table1 r1, table2 r2 
  where  startX = (select X from table2 where id = r1.id and intersectionId =
  (select intersectionId from table3 where id = r1.id and linkId= r1.linkid  and LinkDirection = positive)) and startY
  = (select Y from table2 where id = r1.id and intersectionId  = 
  (select intersectionId from table3 where id = r1.id and linkId= r1.linkid  and LinkDirection = negative));
```

Comment: what is shapepointtype, you dont have such column in table1.

Comment: @kaleel: Ignore that. I have removed it from the query. APologies!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: That's why I love ORM frameworks or tools. I don't like sql command at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this query you should be able to do it.

Pay attention on LinkDirection if it's text.

```
SELECT 
    t1.ID
    ,t1.LinkId
    ,t2_start.X as X_Start
    ,t2_start.Y as Y_Start
    ,t2_end.X as X_End
    ,t2_end.Y as Y_End
FROM    
    table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table3 t3_start
        on t1.linkId = t3_start.linkId  
        and t3_start.LinkDirection = 'Positive'
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2_start
        on t2_start.IntersectionID = t3_start.IntersectionID 

    LEFT JOIN table3 t3_end
        on t1.linkId = t3_end.linkId  
        and t3_end.LinkDirection = 'negative'
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2_end
        on t2_end.IntersectionID = t3_end.IntersectionID
```

You will get null field in `t2_start.X t2_start.Y t2_end.X t2_end.Y` if there is no row in table2. You can change it to 0 or -1 with

`CASE WHEN  t2_start.X is not null THEN t2_start.X ELSE -1 END`

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below query is usefull, if you need clarification. Please ask

```
SELECT ID,LinkID,MAX(StartX) AS StartX ,MAX(Starty) AS StartY,
MAX(EndX) AS EndX,MAX(EndY) AS EndY FROM
(
  SELECT a.ID,a.LinkID,X as StartX,Y as StartY,null as EndX,null as EndY  
   FROM 
          table1 a JOIN table3 b 
               ON a.Linkid=b.Linkid 
          JOIN table2 c 
               ON b.id=c.id WHERE LinkDirection='Positive'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a.ID,a.LinkID,null as StartX,null as StartY,X as EndX,Y as EndYY 
   FROM 
          table1 a JOIN table3 b 
                ON a.Linkid=b.Linkid 
          JOIN table2 c 
                ON b.id=c.id WHERE LinkDirection='Negative'
) t
GROUP BY ID,LinkID
```

This will return

```
ID  LinkID  StartX  StartY   EndX    EndY
1     0      100     200     300     400
2     1      NULL    NULL    100     200
```

Comment: You should take a look on my answer :)

Comment: @Ryx5 I did before posting my answer. Please correct following changes, LinkDirection belongs to table3 not table2, The Left Join return Null rows and the Start and End values will appear in separate rows.

Comment: @Ryx5 Its working. Hint : to remove records with null, use Join instead of Left Join

Comment: I think it's interesting to get the null values (and change it if needed)
It was a pleasure to share with you.

Comment: @Kaleel :  Thanks a lot. I added Indexes on all my needed fields and performance improves a great well. Thank you once again :)